# Overriding interface method in Java

Tags: java, javafx, methods, interface, overriding

I am trying to use an existing package to create my own app upon it. However I do not know how to call an interface parametrized method.

On the package that uses JavaFX there is a class that's constructor is

```
public class App extends Application{
...
protected App(Logic logic) {
    this(logic.configuration().welcomeScreen, logic.configuration().name, Optional.of(logic));
}
}
```

And the interface is this:

```
public interface Logic extends X, Y {

default Configuration configuration() {
    return new Configuration(1000, "Hello world", true);
}
default void initialize() {
    System.out.println("Starting the application.");
}
}
```

And Configuration goes like this:

```
public final class Configuration {
public final int tick;
public final String name;
public final boolean welcomeScreen;

public Configuration(int tick, String name, boolean welcomeScreen) {
    this.tick = tick;
    this.name = name;
    this.welcomeScreen = welcomeScreen;
}
}
```

output of App:

```
 (1000, "Hello world", true)
```

Now when I create my own extension of App the override doesn't go through:

```
public class Test extends App implements Logic{  
@Override
public Configuration configuration() {
    return new Configuration(25, "Test", true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

launch(args); //launches the App
}

}
```

output:

```
(1000, "Hello world", true)
```

The App still calls the default method of the interface.
What is the reason for this and how to bypass the default method in this case?

Comment: How do you print the output? Where is the constructor of `App` that doesn't take parameters? (There's no constructor implementation in `Test` which would result in a compile time error, if there was such constructor available in the superclass.) Are you absolutely sure it's `Test` that is launched (do `System.out.println(getClass());` to check). Furthermore note that the `App` constructor calls `configuration()` twice which creates 2 instances instead of 1. You should add a private constructor taking 2 parameters, `Configuration`and `Logic`, to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subclass should declare a constructor that invokes the following parent constructor explicitly :

```
protected App(Logic logic) {
    this(logic.configuration().welcomeScreen, logic.configuration().name, Optional.of(logic));
}
```

Otherwise it will not compile according to the posted code... And if it compiles it means that the parent class has a no arg constructor. That will be implicitly invoked (in the compiled class) and that is not what you want to invoke to use the overrided `configuration()` method.

App and Logic should not be coupled in `Test`.
So you could introduce a class to define the `Logic` subclass :

```
public TestLogic implements Logic{         
  @Override
  public AppConfiguration configuration() {
    return new AppConfiguration(25, "Test", true);
  }
}
```

And add the `Test` constructor to pass the `Logic` instance (here `this`):

```
public class Test extends App {     
  public Test() {
     super(new TestLogic());
  } 
}
```

Comment: It is a JavaFX application so `Test` is probably instantiated automatically in the background.

Comment: It sounds right. I don't know a lot JavaFX. Thanks.

Comment: Got an `error: cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called` to `super(this)`. Tried to do `App(this)` but it did not recognize App. Shouldn't the App class load first? EDIT: My bad didn't see the comment that it's here this. I can't see a way to pass interface to a constructor as parameter.

Comment: My bad too. I forgot an elementary rule : a constructor cannot refer `this` while invoking a constructor. I updated.